# How can I read location from multiple users using React Native and Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have a react native project and I'm using firebase db, but I'm new using it so I'm having some trouble. I'm trying to retrieve and read location from multiple users with unique uid, for now this is my query (which returns all data):

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const userObj = snapshot.val();
  console.log(userObj);
});
```

And this is my firebase realtime:

```
-users 
    -->BAEjWfhiZiWnMv0VGwNCZFfAA7q1 
       -name: Anna
       -age: 34
       -location: 
         ---latitude: -22.7525031 
         ---longitude: -28.7525031 
    -->RMOQm1Uk3aZMbHpSpggcCU5vH8T2 
        -name:Chris
        -age:56
        -location 
         ---latitude: -29.7525031  
         ---longitude: -32.7525031
```

But what I really want is to get this output:

```
BAEjWfhiZiWnMv0VGwNCZFfAA7q1
latitude: -22.7525031 
longitude: -28.7525031 

RMOQm1Uk3aZMbHpSpggcCU5vH8T2 
latitude: -29.7525031  
longitude: -32.7525031
```

Is there a way to retrieve only user's unique uid with their locations?

Comment: The problem is, are you getting more information than you need?

Comment: No, I'm going to use name and age in another screen, so all is needed.

Comment: What do you mean with `Is there a way to retrieve only user's unique uid with their locations?`?

Comment: Get data from users will retrieve all tree. So if you want to get the second structure you'll need to put it on another tree (I'm not sure about the term I haven't used it in a while).

Comment: I changed the way I'm handling it, it will be better to keep data about the user in another node, so I separated user's personal info from user's geolocation. Thank you!!